# Trouble with spring jpa data native Sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

All my repositories are extending commonService Repository which in return are extending JpaRepository and JpaSpecification

```
public interface CommonReadRepository<T>
        extends JpaRepository<T, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
```

i want to define native Sql query in CommonReadRepository like :
Mysql:select * from table limit 1,20;

> @Query(value = "select * from ?1 limit ?2,?3", nativeQuery = true)

```
 List<?> customFindQuery(String tableName,int offset,int limit);
```

but i recieve SqlGrammerException and unfortunately , i did not find much about syntax in documentation.

i know if i can define the queries in repositories then i know the table name but is it possible to make it generic ?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps if you post the full stack trace then there would be more info to actually comment on. More like a MySQL exception ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base Repository Section defined in Spring data [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

follow the guidelines defined in the reference like the following :

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface CommonReadRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

  List<T> custonFindQuery();
}
@Repository
interface UserRepository extends CommonReadRepository<User, Long> {
  User findByEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress);
}
```

For your specific query `List<?> customFindQuery(String tableName,int offset,int limit);`

its already support in `JpaRepository` by calling the method:

```
Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)
```

For example:

```
Page<User> all = userRepository .findAll(new PageRequest(3, 10));
```

where offest = 30 (3 x 10), and limit = 10